# OpenSSL - I got an error on CRL generation (error creating serial number index:(2,7,9))

Tags: openssl

When I try to generate a CRL file, I get this error :

`error creating serial number index:(2,7,9)`

verbose mode says :

```
...
11 entries loaded from the database
generating index
error creating serial number index:(2,7,9)
```

Any idea what is going on to help me fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details. For example, how did you try to generate your CRL file ?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly, I found what happened :

It was caused by duplicate entries : 
- 1 entry "Valid" for Certificate "X"
- 1 entry "Revoked" for the same certificate "X"

I got duplicate entries because I  manually rebuilt the database file because we had a bug in our cleanup script which ran aginst it.

I removed the "Valid" entry and I was able to generate new CRL.